# Cross terms based columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How should I generate the data2 from data1? 
The rows of data2 should be the corss terms of data1.
Thanks in advance!

> ```
> data1 = pd.DataFrame([('1M, 6M, 1Y'), ('1M, 6M, 1Y')])
>             0
> 0  1M, 6M, 1Y
> 1  1M, 6M, 1Y
> ```

> ```
> data2 = pd.DataFrame([('1M', '1M'),
>                      ('1M', '6M'),
>                      ('1M', '1Y'),
>                      ('6M', '1M'),
>                      ('6M', '6M'),
>                      ('6M', '1Y'),
>                      ('1Y', '1M'),
>                      ('1Y', '6M'),
>                      ('1Y', '1Y'),])
>
>     0   1
> 0  1M  1M
> 1  1M  6M
> 2  1M  1Y
> 3  6M  1M
> 4  6M  6M
> 5  6M  1Y
> 6  1Y  1M
> 7  1Y  6M
> 8  1Y  1Y
> ```

Comment: Have you had a chance to give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
index_s0 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([data1[0][0].split(','), data1[0][0].split(',')], names=["0", "1"])
so_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index_s0).reset_index()


out:
     0    1
0   1M   1M
1   1M   6M
2   1M   1Y
3   6M   1M
4   6M   6M
5   6M   1Y
6   1Y   1M
7   1Y   6M
8   1Y   1Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

out = pd.DataFrame(product(*(x.split(', ') for x in data1[0])),
                   columns=data1.index) # optional
```

*NB. this should work with any number of rows.*

output:

```
    0   1
0  1M  1M
1  1M  6M
2  1M  1Y
3  6M  1M
4  6M  6M
5  6M  1Y
6  1Y  1M
7  1Y  6M
8  1Y  1Y
```